# Convergence in distribution and independence

Tags: measure-theory, weak-convergence

Consider two sequences of random variables $\{X_n\}_{n \in \mathbb{N}}$ and $\{Y_n\}_{n \in \mathbb{N}}$ such that $X_n \rightarrow_{d} X$ and $Y_n \rightarrow_{d} Y$ and $X_n$ is independent of $Y_n$ for every $n \in \mathbb{N}$. Does $(X_n, Y_n) \rightarrow_d(X,Y)$?

If not can someone suggest a counter example?

Comment: Note that you also need $X$ to be assumed indpendent of $Y$.

Comment: Is there a counterexample in case $X$ is not independent of $Y$?

Comment: If you believe the comments you've gotten so far, then any $X_n$ and $Y_n$ that fits into the above setting would be a counter example.

Answer (score 1):

As @WoolierThanThou mentioned in the comment, the statement could be wrong without assuming the independence of $X$ and $Y$. Here is a counterexample.

Let $X \equiv Y \sim N(0, 1)$, and $X_n$ be a sequence of $N(0, 1)$ random variables that are independent of $X$, $Y_n$ be a sequence of $N(0, 1)$ random variables that are independent of $\{X_n\}$ and $X$. Then trivially $X_n \to_d X$ and $Y_n \to_d Y$.

Consider the set $A = \{(x, y): x \leq 0, y \leq 0\}$ with $\partial A = \{(x, y): x = 0, y \leq 0\} \cup \{(x, y): x \leq 0, y = 0\}$. Since $P[(X, X) \in \partial A] = 2P[X = 0, X \leq 0] - P[X = 0, X = 0] = 0$, $A$ is a continuity set. On the other hand, since $(X_n, Y_n) \sim N_2(0, I_{(2)})$, we have
\begin{align*}
P[(X_n, Y_n) \in A] = P[X_n \leq 0]P[Y_n \leq 0] = \frac{1}{2}\times\frac{1}{2}
= \frac{1}{4} \not\to P[(X, X) \in A] = P[X \leq 0] = \frac{1}{2},
\end{align*}
showing that $(X_n, Y_n) \not\to_d (X, X)$.